# Flutter for loop to generate a Row of widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a string which contains text with multiple `\n`, I want to display that text in the new line but with a leading icon.

For e.g, If I have a `String str="Hello\nThere\nUser"`. I want to display the text like this:

```
Icon  Hello
Icon  There
Icon  User
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    String str = "Hello\nThere\nUser";
    List<String> list = str.split('\n');
    list.forEach((s) {
      widgetList.add(Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.directions_car),
          Text(s),
        ],
      ));
    });

    return Column(children: widgetList);
```

or

```
    String str = "Hello\nThere\nUser";
    return Column(
      children: [
        for (var s in str.split('\n'))
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.directions_run),
              Text(s),
            ],
          )
      ],
    );
```